Программа завершается раньше времени при отправке GET запроса
Пытался создать HttpClient и сделать запрос, который вернул бы мне статус код. Но на строке
using var result = await client.GetAsync("https://google.com");
просто завершается программа без каких-либо ошибок. Подскажите что не так, или почему так происходит.
Вот мой код:
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;


internal class Program
{
    static async void HttpTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Приложение начало работу");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using var result = await client.GetAsync("https://google.com");
            Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Приложение завершило работу");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpTest();
    }
}


Я понял как исправить код, чтобы все работало. Однако все равно не понимаю почему функция не выполняется полностью.

Прочитайте про async/await. В вашем случае вы запускаете Task (асинхронную задачу), и не дожидаетесь ее. Также консольное окно по умолчанию сразу закрывается, если не ожидать иного. Так что, void Main переделываем в async Task Main, HttpTest() переделываем на await HttpTest(), после которой ждем действия от пользователя Console.ReadLine();, ну а async void HttpTest() переделываем на async Task HttpTest(). И да, замечу, HttpClient должен создаваться один раз и жить все время жизни приложения, а не по каждому вызову метода.

Не используйте async void
static async Task HttpTest()
{
    // ...ваш код
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await HttpTest();
}

Как верно заметил @EvgeniyZ в комментарии, проблема в том что вы запускаете асинхронную задачу, и не дожидаетесь её завершения.

Так у вас нет ожидания завершения операции. Да, внутри метода HttpTestвы используете await для ожидания, но весь метода HttpTest является асинхронным, по этому так же нужно ожидать его завершения при вызове.
Первый вариант, вы можете поставить в конце Main команду Console.ReadLine() для ожидания ввода с клавиатуры. Такой вызов поможет вам дождаться завершения исполнения метода HttpTest.
Второй вариант это использовать Task подобным образом:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task httpTask = Task.Run(async () => { await HttpTest() });
    Task.WaitAll(httpTask)
}

UPD:
Ещё стоит отметить, что у вас сам метод HttpTest возвращает void и в этом большая проблема, потому что void нельзя ожидать. При использовании асинхронных методов рекомендую заменить void на Task для контролированного завершения задач

Зачем вот это Task.Run(async () => { await HttpTest() }) нужно? Почему не просто Task httpTask = HttpTest();? Хотя вообще всё тело метода Main можно здесь свести к одной строчке HttpTest().Wait(); и получить тот же эффект. И даже в последнем варианте всё равно интересно: чем вариант с async Task Main и await хуже?

@aepot Если из этого ответа выкинуть всё лишнее, то получится ваш ответ, конечно )

async Task Main поддерживается не по всех версиях .net. Зачем вот это Task.Run(async () => { await HttpTest() }) нужно? Ну я даже не знаю как вам объяснить даже... Попробуйте что ли документацию Microsoft почитать

По поводу ответа. Console.ReadLine() поможет дождаться ответа только в том случае, если пользователь угадает, сколько нужно ждать и не будет нажимать Enter достаточное время. Нельзя на такие вещи слепо полагаться.

@CrazyElf, если пользователь угадает, сколько нужно ждать? Это как? Там дефолтный таймаут стоит на HttpClient, не помню сколько, то там не получится ждать очень долго. Если это ставить какой-то Thread.Sleep, то там да, уже придётся пальцем в небо тыкать

@Faraday Вы тоже почитайте документацию. Task.WaitAll принимает на вход список задач, единичную задачу не принимает )  Ну и непонятно зачем ещё одну задачу запускать, если можно ожидать сразу HttpTest.

@CrazyElf Task.WaitAll принимает, у него есть params перегрузка.

Попробуйте что ли документацию Microsoft почитать - я не читая знаю наверняка, что это излишний и максимально странный код. Но мне интересно, что же за годы программирования под .NET я в этой документации по вашему мнению упустил? Если интересно, задайте отдельный вопрос, почему этот код излишний и странный даже для древнего фреймворка, в деталях объясню.
